# How to read Excel sheet for specific rows and columns

Tags: java, groovy, apache-poi

I want to read Excel sheet from specific row number and only want some specific columns value. I tried lots of stuff, but I don't get proper output as expected.
Below is my code snippet:

```
public class ReadExcel {

File src=new File("F:\\ucd\\UAT_Patch_31012018.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook wb;
XSSFSheet Sheet1;
FileOutputStream fileOut;

public void ReadExcel1() throws Exception{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
    XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet Sheet1=wb.getSheetAt(0);

    int rowcount=Sheet1.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    int colcount=Sheet1.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();

    for(int i=6;i<=9;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=rowcount;j++){
            String testdata1=Sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
            System.out.println(testdata1);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
ReadExcel read=new ReadExcel();
read.ReadExcel1();
}
}
```

Excel file format:

```
File Name     Target Server   Target Path
abc/Abc.txt    10.0.43.101  /home/urbancode/UrbanCode/Test/DeployableComponent/abc
pqr/Abc.txt               /home/urbancode/UrbanCode/Test/DeployableComponent/pqr
xyz/Abc.txt                 /home/urbancode/UrbanCode/Test/DeployableComponent/xyz
```

I want to save my output in temp.txt file as below:

```
 abc/Abc.txt;/home/urbancode/UrbanCode/Test/DeployableComponent/abc
 pqr/Abc.txt;/home/urbancode/UrbanCode/Test/DeployableComponent/pqr
```

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+cells%2C+with+control+of+missing+%2F+blank+cells

Comment: Please get the Row first and then iterate the columns 6to9 and print them. What you are currently doing is printing column6 values of all rows, then column7 of all rows and so on. Use a RowIterator and print the  values.

Comment: @BarathVutukuri I tried with RowIterator but I am not able to do, will you plz send the sample code snippet  for reference for above scenario, Thanks

Comment: @vivekbangare  see sample code [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TechieGenie/e019f5b8305cede6d88b8d66aa09aa45/raw/e6574063def11b905e0abc79edc2c7ea57cf0b09/rows.java)